# Literature on liquidity risk: Amihud (2002) vs Pastor and Stambaugh (2003)

Tags: factor-models, liquidity

Why is it the case that literature which studies liquidity risk often use the Amihud (2002) measure, whilst in factor pricing a liquidity portfolio based on the Pastor and Stambaugh (2003) liquidity portfolio is used? Is there a specific reason for this? PS (2003) study unexpected shocks in the aggregate market liquidity which makes it useful to include in a factor model. However, for Amihud (2002) you could sum the individual liquidity measures, obtain the market liquidity and run an AR(2) model on the market liquidity and take the residuals, right? What makes PS (2003) measure more suitable for a factor model?

Comment: At least PS are usually credited for the idea that market liquidity is a priced factor: stocks that do poorly in low market liquidity states should earn higher returns. Amihud proposed a liquidity measure but didn’t use such a factor model and is hence less cited in such a context.